# Stop link action if onclick function returns false

Tags: javascript, html

Here is a function that simply checks if a radio button has been selected on a form element.

```
function validate_selected(element) {
    var radios = document.getElementsByName(element);
    var formValid = false;

    var i = 0;
    while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
      if (radios[i].checked) formValid = true;
      i++;        
    }

    if (!formValid) alert("Must select one before moving on!");
    return formValid;
}
```

Here is my link that I want disabled if the function returns false. Right now the link shows the alert but after the alert the link sends the user forward.

```
<a href="#m2" data-role="button" onclick="validate_selected('owner');"><p style="font-size:<?php echo $size1.'px'; ?>;">Next</p></a>
```

I want the link to be disabled if the function returns false.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You almost got it, you needed to add the 'return' in the function aswell:

```
onclick="return validate_selected('owner');"
```

Also a small tip, add a break:

```
while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
    if (radios[i].checked){
        formValid = true; 
        break; // No need to continue any more, we've found a selected option
    }
    i++;        
}
```

---

I've changed your `onclick` from inline to the proper way to handle events, and made a working demo. Just remove the onclick from the button and add this:

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick =function(){ validate_selected('owner'); };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WX6v7/1/ (added some radiobuttons in the example)

Comment: That second part is slightly incorrect, his while loop states `while` `!formValid`. So as soon as thats set to true, the `while` will exit. Your approach is better practice though.

Comment: Still not working with the return added! Changed the while to: while (i < radios.length) and added the break. I was thinking the same thing!

Comment: @matty, you are right, I missed that part. The break isnt it though

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I see that, I'm still having issues implementing it on my page. I've copied my code over to fiddle and it works as well, but the whole page I'm working on doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Would position of the javascript mater on the real page? Right now it is before the html elements.

Comment: The js first. You need to define the function first before you can use it

Answer (score 3):

You need to actually `return` the value in the `onclick` that your function returned:

```
onclick="return validate_selected('owner');">
```